# How to write a .bat file to automate starting to different repos?

Tags: batch-file

*Background:*

I am working on **two** different repositories. To start up the app, I have to run a few `npm` commands on each repositories and then run `npm run start` on each. I tried to write a `.bat` file to automate this process. This `.bat` looks something like this:

**.bat file:**

```bash
echo "Navigating to repo #1..."
cd path\to\first\repo
echo "Starting docker..."
npm run docker:start
echo "Starting repo #1..."
npm start
echo "Navigating to repo #2..."
cd path\to\second\repo
echo "Starting repo #2..."
npm start
```

When double-clicking this `.bat` file, the commands get executed until (and including) line #6. This is because once the first server starts, a process keeps running to watch changes on this server without returning anything. So in fact, the executer never gets past line #6; and lines #7 forward never get executed.

*The question is:*
How can I edit this `.bat` file, so that I can run `npm start` on both repos?

***Note that:***
The order is important. So repo #1 has to have been started before starting repo #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` is your friend.

Read `help start` and try

```
echo "Navigating to repo #1..."
cd path\to\first\repo

echo "Starting docker..."
npm run docker:start

start "repo1" npm start

echo "Navigating to repo #2..."
cd path\to\second\repo
start "repo 2" npm start
```